# Assign enumerate output to Pandas dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, enumerate

grateful for your help.  I've pulled together the script below, which takes a list of PDFs within a CSV file and downloads them.  This script works.

The only thing I'm trying to do is to save the generated filenames (file-0.pdf, file-1.pdf, etc) into a Pandas dataframe alongside the URL it was generated from.  The script currently saves all filenames as 'file-1.pdf'.

How can I take the enumerated values and insert these into the dataframe?

Thanks so much for your help!

```
def url_to_pdf(i, url, file_path):

  filename = 'file-{}.pdf'.format(i)
  full_path = '{}{}'.format(file_path, filename)
  urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_path)

  print('{} saved.'.format(filename))

  df['filename'] = (filename)

FILENAME = 'pdfs_urls.csv'
FILE_PATH = 'Demo_Contents/PDFs/'

urls = pd.read_csv(FILENAME)

for i, url in enumerate(urls.values):
  url_to_pdf(i, url[0], FILE_PATH)
```

Comment: why does your function return `None` instead of the data frame info?

Comment: this was a typo - thanks, good spot.  I want the script to return the files names it creates for the files it downloads

Comment: It looks like it doesn't return anything now...

Comment: Pretty sure this line in the function is writing the whole column/series each time. df['filename'] = (filename) it is overwriting file-0 with file-1. You should pass in the index or row and update with .iat or another method. You want to write one cell at a time not the series.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that might the case, but can't seem to work out how.  Any ideas?